# MacOS 10.13.5 - Updated yesterday, getting spammed with System Extension Blocked

Tags: macos, high-sierra

I updated my Macbook yesterday to the most recent update. After restarting I got spammed by tons of System Extension Blocked messages. 
[image: System Extension Blocked]
Opening Security Preferences - THERE IS NO ALLOW BUTTON. 
[image: Security options screen - no ALLOW button showing]

How can I get around this? This is super frustrating. And it isn't just for Parallels. I get it for other apps too.

Comment: What operating system were you on previously? I think Apple started blocking unsigned Extensions.

Comment: It could've been 10.13.

Comment: For now I've turned off SIP. Parallels suggested I disable it

Comment: Yeah....not the best idea

Comment: what if you click the lock and authenticate, anything pop up or under the Advanced button? Failing that I would uninstall and then reinstall Parallels as a test case and see what happens.

Comment: Nothing shows up. I've tried reinstalling. No difference. Everytime I restart the Mac I get bombarded with the popups. It's not just Parallels either. It's other programs that were perfectly fine before the update.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This answer on a different copy of this question is a solution with a tradeoff: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/327816/292890

Summary is: <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> on boot to get Recovery Mode, then open Terminal by clicking on **Utilities > Terminal**. Once open, enter the following command:

```
spctl kext-consent disable
```

It disables kernel extension security confirmations altogether, which of course hurts your security, but it does prevent all the confirmation popups. That's also less drastic I think than disabling SIP entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad I migrated my home folder and applications to a separate partition, because it turned out that not even reinstalling the OS solved this problem unless it was a clean install.

I had this problem in High Sierra, updated to Mojave but it persisted. Reinstalled the OS, but no change. Finally wiped the partition (or APFS volume in this case) and reinstalled Mojave on it. Linked in my home folder, and the problem was finally gone. The same should probably work for High Sierra.