# Uninstall blocked system extensions?

Tags: mojave

Every time macOS Mojave starts (and High Sierra before that) and I log in I get six dialog boxes saying a system extension is blocked. The only information it gives me is the name of the organisation that signed the extension -- two each for Intel, Oracle and Logitech.

One of the dialog buttons directs me to the security section of system settings, where I'm expecting an *Allow* button. The button is not there, much like [described in this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/327716/40713).

Since that question has no proper solution, and since it seems that not even updating from High Sierra to Mojave makes any difference, I'm wondering how to uninstall these system extensions altogether so that they stop generating these annoying dialog boxes everytime I reboot. I.e. right now I'm not even sure how to go about identifying each application that installed one of the extensions that I can't allow, let alone how they can be removed.

#### What I've tried

- Uninstalling the one application that I know of, Logitech Gaming Software. After that the Logitech dialog did not appear after reboot, instead its place was taken up by even more dialogs with "Oracle" and "Intel".
- Reinstalling that Logitech software, during whose install I get spammed with five system extension dialogs from Logitech at a time. If I close them five new dialogs will appear shortly after. Sometimes mixed with dialogs regarding some other developer, for good measure. It's basically a never ending torrent of dialog boxes at this point.
- Guessed that the extension from Intel might be HAXM installed with Android Studio, and the one from Oracle is Java installed with IntelliJ IDEA. Moved both apps to the trash and rebooted, but as expected that made no difference. I found no uninstall utilities for those apps.
- Uninstalled the Logitech software with its uninstaller, and removed everything Logitech related in /Library/Extensions.
- Guessed that the Oracle extension was VirtualBox, and ran its uninstall script. It did not remove any VirtualBox kexts in /Library/Extensions. I wal also unable to install VirtualBox after that.

I should add that I have in a previous install of Mojave been able to allow all of these system extensions (probably) using a then existent *Allow* button.